# How to write a makefile for llvm IR

Tags: makefile, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

If I have 3 files, function.h, function.c and my_program.c which calls a method in function.h all in the same directory, what would be the best way to write a makefile so that I end up with a my_program.bc that would actually run when I type in lli my_program.bc? (I need to run a user defined pass that would insert stuff into the functions - should I run the pass on function.bc and test.bc, or should I link before running the pass?)

I've tried llvm-link function.bc my_program.bc with no luck. I feel I'm either missing something simple or going about the whole thing wrong.

Current terrible none-working makefile:

```
.PHONY: all clean
CC = clang
CFLAGS  = -std=gnu99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L -g -Wall
IRFLAGS = -O3 -emit-llvm
TARGET = test
DEPS = functions.h
all: $(TARGET)
bc: test2

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

%.bc: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(IRFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

test2: test.bc functions.bc
    llvm-link -o test2.bc $< functions.bc


test: test.o functions.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^


clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET) *.o *.bc
```

Comment: Does not really answer your question, but have you tried making clang run the pass directly?

Comment: Yes, the pass works and runs, and the test executable works too. My issue is linking and making the original program run in bc format.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write a normal Makefile to produce the desired executable,
then use wllvm?

Shameless plug for wllvm:

https://github.com/SRI-CSL/whole-program-llvm

I do not use lli, so I would be interested to hear about how it resolved
any reliance on stdlibc that your program may have.